# How can I get the time it takes a function to test the performance of functions in Kotlin

Tags: performance, kotlin

I need to check how long does a function need to run. I have the following functions which address the same task:

**mixAnimalsA**

```
fun mixAnimalsA(a1: Animal, a2: Animal) =
        when (setOf(a1, a2)) {
            setOf(Animal.OWL, Animal.Leopard) -> Beast.OWLPARD
            setOf(Animal.ELEPHANT, Animal.BUTTERFLY) -> Beast.BUTTERPHANT
            else -> throw Exception("Not possible combination")
        }
```

**mixAnimalsB**

```
fun mixAnimalsB(a1: Animal, a2: Animal) =
        when (setOf(a1, a2)) {
            (c1 == Animal.OWL && c2 == Animal.Leopard) ||
                    (c2 == Animal.OWL && c1 == Animal.Leopard) -> Beast.OWLPARD
            (c1 == Animal.ELEPHANT && c2 == Animal.BUTTERFLY) ||
                    (c2 == Animal.ELEPHANT && c1 == Animal.BUTTERFLY)-> Beast.BUTTERPHANT
            else -> throw Exception("Not possible combination")
        }
```

`Animal` and `Beast` are enumerations. How can I measure how long each function takes to run?

Comment: As a slight performance improvement, you could try out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you're looking for an in-code solution, you can use [`measureTimeMillis`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/measure-time-millis.html) and [`measureNanoTime`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/measure-nano-time.html), like this:

```
val time = measureTimeMillis {
    // call your function here
}
```

They return the measured time in milliseconds and nanoseconds, respectively.

Comment: Please note that this method will likely return different results from run to run. For any meaningful performance comparison use JMH

Comment: @zsmb13 `measureTimeMillis` returns zero for any function. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: @zsmb13 yes, divide result value by 1000F to get the time in seconds. It's being rounded to int in your case.

Answer (score 35):

### Measure execution time and also keep the result

#### Standard Library

The standard library function `measureTimedValue` may be used to measure execution time and at the same time capture the result. This tuple of values is being exposed as a [TimedValue(value: T, duration: Duration)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-timed-value/):

```
@ExperimentalTime
fun main() {
    val (result: String, duration: Duration) = measureTimedValue {
        operation()
    }
    
    print("Got $result after ${duration.inMilliseconds} ms.")
}
```

Note that this API is experimental and requires explicit opt-in.

#### Obsolete custom implementation

(This used to be my answer before the standard lib was extended)

If you want to measure the execution time and also access the measured function's return value afterward, here's a custom solution:

```
inline fun <R> executeAndMeasureTimeMillis(block: () -> R): Pair<R, Long> {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = block()
    return result to (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
val (response, duration) = executeAndMeasureTimeMillis {
    restTemplate.getForObject<AnyObject>(uri)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's enough to get the time as output on the console:

```
fun <T> timeIt(message: String = "", block: () -> T): T {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val r = block()
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("$message: ${end - start} ms")
    return r
}
```

Usage:

```
val result = timeIt("note about the code") {
   // do something...
}
```

Output (example):

> note about the code: 1ms

Comment: according to https://www.techiedelight.com/measure-elapsed-time-kotlin/ System.currentTimeMillis() is not accurate. What do ou think? I am planning to use  System.nanoTime()

Answer (score 0):

For the benchmark of some code block and getting the result a same time, i do some refactor of the standard method in TimingKt class
to give us output generic result and at the same time display a given log.
Here is my example :

```
/**
     * Executes the given block and show the elapsed time in milliseconds in a given message.
     *
     * @param block which will be bench marked
     * @param logMessage log message to be displayed
     *
     * @return a generic result
     *
     */
    private fun <T> measureTime(block: () -> T, logMessage: String): T {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val t = block()
        val consumedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
        Log.d(TAG, "Calculation of $logMessage time :$consumedTime milliseconds")
        return t
    }
```

And how it will be used :

```
return measureTime({ 
// given block with return result
}, "message to be displayed typically the name of method which will be calculated")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple time test code.

```
class TimeCounter(val name: String) {
    var totalTime: Long = 0
        private set

    var count: Int = 0
        private set

    var minTime: Long = Long.MAX_VALUE
        private set

    var maxTime: Long = Long.MIN_VALUE
        private set

    fun addTime(time: Long) {
        this.count++
        this.totalTime += time

        if (this.minTime > time) {
            this.minTime = time
        }

        if (this.maxTime < time) {
            this.maxTime = time
        }
    }

    val averageTime: Double
        get() = this.totalTime / this.count.toDouble()

    fun printTime() {
        println("(time about : '$name'), totalTime : $totalTime, count : $count, " +
                "average : $averageTime, minTime : $minTime, maxTime : $maxTime")
    }

    fun <T> runWithTimeCount(run: () -> T): T {
        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        return run().also {
            this.addTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
        }
    }
}
```

you can use 'TimeCounter' like this, (example)

```
var sum = 0
val testTimeCounter = TimeCounter("logic1")
for(i in 0 until 100){
    sum += testTimeCounter.runWithTimeCount { 
        logic1(i) // your logic
    }
}

println(sum)
testTimeCounter.printTime() // totalTime, average, minTime, maxTime
```

Answer (score 0):

**Execute function, measure its performance and logs performance** - in same call

*this solution will help folks who want to measure and log performance, execute function at same time, also is a cleaner approach when there is multiple performance measurement involved of different functions*

Create functions as such:

```
//the inline performance measurement method
private inline fun <T> measurePerformanceInMS(
        logger: (Long) -> Unit,
        function: () -> T)
: T {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result: T = function.invoke()
    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    logger.invoke( endTime - startTime)
    return result
}

//the logger function
fun logPerf(time: Long){
    Log.d("TAG","PERFORMANCE IN MS: $time ms ")
}

//the function whose performance needs to be checked
fun longRunningFunction() : Int{
    var x = 0
    for (i in 1..20000) x++
    return x
}
```

This way you can keep logging, performance computation and function execution under a single function call and no code replication needed.

If you require nano second measurement then use `System.nanoTime()`

**USAGE** :

```
val endResult = measurePerformanceInMS({time -> logPerf(time)}){
            longRunningFunction()
        }
```

**NOTE** : here the *'endResult'* will carry the result of function whose performance was being measured.